# Error when querying time series data from GridDB using SQL in Ubuntu

Tags: python, database, griddb

```sql
   SELECT * 
   FROM my_time_series_table 
   WHERE timestamp >= '2023-01-01' AND timestamp <= '2023-02-01';
```

I am trying to query time series data from my GridDB database using SQL in Ubuntu. However, I keep encountering an error when executing the query. The error message I receive is:

> "Unknown column 'timestamp' in 'where clause'".

I have already confirmed that the 'timestamp' column exists in the 'my_time_series_table'. What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

[Timestamp](https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_5/GridDB_SQL_Reference.html#timestamp) is a type in Grid DB, so you will need to wrap quotes around your column name to let the db management system know it's a name:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM my_time_series_table 
   WHERE "timestamp" >= '2023-01-01' AND "timestamp" <= '2023-02-01';
```